# Sorting an integer array which contains a range of elements k

Tags: java, sorting

I am looking for a solution where we have a range of elements k say [1-4] in an integer array say [1,2,1,3,4,2,1,3,2,3,1,4,2] like this and they need to be sorted with a minimum time complexity in Core Java.

Can someone please help me solve this with minimum time complexity.

Comment: What have you tried? There are numerous question on SO on this topic. Is [google](http://www.google.com) down?

Comment: Believing this is somewhat school-related, read up on different sorting algorithms, implement the one you find suitable, and sort the array. http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/

Comment: Thanks guys for your help. The http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/ is good place to start.

Comment: Hint: the solution is `O(N)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just scan the input once, count into an array and expand it again; this will as far as I can tell give `n+m` complexity, where `n` is the length of the array, and `m` is the length of the range; if you use an ordered O(1) hash instead of the array, you may be able to push it close to O(n).

```java
    int range_min = 1, range_max = 4;

    int[] input        = {1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 4, 2};
    int[] output       = new int[input.length];
    int[] intermediate = new int[range_max-range_min+1];

    for(int num : input)                        
        intermediate[num-range_min]++;

    int cnt = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<range_max-range_min+1; i++)  
        for(int j=0; j<intermediate[i]; j++)
            output[cnt++] = i+range_min;
```

Answer (score 3):

Count how many  1s, 2s, 3s, and 4s you've got, then put the numbers back according to the count:

```
int[] count = new int[5]; // 0..4
for (int a : data) {
    data[a]++;
}
int p = 0;
for (int i = 0 ; i != count.length ; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j != count[i] ; j++) {
        data[p++] = i;
    }
}
```

This has a linear time complexity despite having two nested loops, because the number of times the innermost assignment is executed equals exactly the number of items in the original array.

Answer (score 0):

Probably `Arrays.sort(...)` will have a minimum time complexity, since it's a solution available directly in Java. What's more it's based on Quicksort (average complexity O(n lg n)), so with high probability it's gonna be the best solution.

Comment: This doesn't mean it's the best solution, specially when the "problem" is modified.

Answer (score 0):

[Counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) is most suitable for such cases, when k is a 'small range'. It has linear (O(n+k)) complexity.

Comment: Thank you - Counting sort will solve my problem in linear time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only sorting intregers Arrays.sort() (Quicksort) is probably the best way to do it, I usually write my own sort interface, so I can have a interface with a compareTo(Obj,Obj), where i can set the 2. Obj as an argument, to sort in diffrent Categorys. E.g. I pass a 1 if I want to sort with views and a 2 if I sort with likes.

If you a have much data to sort (e.g. defragging), which can cunsume more ram than you have aviable, you would use mergesort, because you dont need to have all the data in your ram to sort it.